# Does the Firewalker DLC have an effect on ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I am kinda tired of those missions. Do they get carried over to ME3 with the save games?

Comment: Do you mean the *Firewalker* DLC?

Comment: And what do you mean "get carried over to ME3"? Are you asking if they have an impact on the game or if you can continue doing those missions in ME3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Firewalker DLC in its entirety has no effect on Mass Effect 3.

This DLC provides:

- Multiple different side quests (5 assignments in 7 locations)
- A new vehicle to explore these side quests (M-44 Hammerhead hovertank)
- A variety of different resources (Paladium, Platinum, etc)
- A prothean relic to store in your captains' quarters
- A fuel depot is added to the Widow system (near the Citadel)

You could view that the resources gathered while completing these missions means you don't have to do as much planet scanning to meet the requirements to upgrade the Normandy before the final mission, but this is very much a personal choice as you can fully upgrade the Normandy without owning the Firewalker DLC.

Comment: just wondering, isn't the conversation between James and Cortez in the hanger during Mass Effect 3 about the difference between the Firewalker and the Mako a result of getting the Firewalker? if so that still counts as effecting Mass Effect 3, if only a very very minor thing